# Create a URL with credentials

Tags: url, forms, url-parameters

I would like to provide links to a website with the credentials already within the link. The link is:

```
https://mychart.covh.org/MyChart/
```

The credentials are:

Username = AllStarUser
Password = FiveStarPassword

I have tried

```
https://mychart.covh.org/MyChart/?Username=AllstarUser,Password=FiveStarPassword
```

and

```
http://mychart.covh.org/Mychart/logincheck.asp?login=AllStarUser&password=FiveStarPassword
```

but these don’t work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is a POST form (`method="post"`). The form data has to be enclosed in the body of the HTTP request.

If it were a GET form (`method="get"`), you could enclose the form data in the URL, which is specified in the header of the HTTP request.

See also:

- HTML 4.1: [Form submission](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/SPSD-html401-20180327/interact/forms.html#h-17.13)
- HTML 5.2: [Form submission](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/sec-forms.html#forms-form-submission)
- Stack Overflow: [How are parameters sent in an HTTP POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request/14551320)

Answer (score 0):

If this was a "get" -

```
https://mychart.covh.org/MyChart/logincheck.asp?Login=AllStarUser&Password=FiveStarPassword
```

would be correct.