# How to find the URL of an item in the dropdown list?

Tags: url, html-select, forms

I need to find/create the URL of the page from its regular URL to automatically apply an option from one of the dropdown items.
On a page, various sort options are available under a dropdown, and I need a URL that would automatically load the page with that particular sort option applied already.

For example:
The given page is - https://club.hihonor.com/in/honor%208x/361/forums.htm
When you select the 'latest posts' option in the dropdown, content changes.
I need a URL that I should type in the browser that would automatically load the content with 'latest posts' option applied, replacing the default load style (most recent).

From the source code of the page, we get this:

[image]

As the ID of the 'Latest posts' is 4, under ListSelect option, I tried these URLs but none of them worked:

- `https://club.hihonor.com/in/honor%208x/361/forums.htm?listSelect=4`
- `https://club.hihonor.com/in/honor%208x/361/forums.htm#listSelect=4`
- `https://club.hihonor.com/in/honor%208x/361/forums.htm#list_topic&list-tool&listSelect=4`
- `https://club.hihonor.com/in/honor%208x/361/forums.htm#list_topic&list-tool&list-select=4`

You can see I have no knowledge of it and am just guessing stuff. Please tell me what URL would directly load the page with topics sorted by 'latest posts'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work for GET forms,
it may or may not work for JavaScript forms, and
it [doesn’t work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54211045/1591669) for POST forms.

In your example, it seems to be a JavaScript form. In that case, it can only work if the programmer provides it as feature. It’s unlikely that it works in this case, as the URL stays the same, no matter which option is selected.

Comment: Ah... okay. BTW, it used to work but they made some changes. Maybe it was GET before. I was using similar URLs that I provide above but they revised them. So, maybe it was intended to block this very thing. No probs. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @John: I see. The URLs you posted use the fragment identifier (everything after `#`) for the feature, which means that it was a JavaScript solution before, too, and that means the programmer either intentionally developed this feature, or used a library that came with it. If the latter is true, maybe they didn’t even realize that this feature is missing now.

Comment: hmm okay. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @John: You’re welcome. If this answered your question, you can accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it -- this marks the question as answered.